# Using Excel IF statement with drop down list

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a fairly simple problem but can't find a solution:
I have a table with a cell that has a drop down function. The user select from that list and I want the next next cell to also be a drop down list but is dependant upon the data in the first drop down

for example

Cell A2 user selects from:

Leeds
London
Liverpool

In B2 the options are now restricted depending upon the data in A2

E.G - Selecting Leeds, returns second drop down of 1,2,3 or 4
Selecting London returns A, B, C, D
Selecting Liverpool returns Cat, Dog, Rabbit

I was looking to use Vlookup tables with an If Statement such as

=if (A2=Leeds(VLookup, C1:C4,2)

However I am hitting an impasse.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating named ranges (Ctrl+F3) with the precise name of the look up, e.g the group Cat, Dog, Rabbit you call Liverpool, then in cell B" in data validation select lists and for the source enter

```
=indirect(A2)
```

Please note you cannot use spaces with Named Range names so you can replace with underscores if need be.